# Android: access activity spinner from fragment

Tags: android, fragment, spinner

I have a main activity which consists of spinner + 3 fragments (tabs). I want to access spinner value from fragment. So I wrote this code into `onActivityCreated` inside my fragment:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinnerOblasti);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        /*TextView[] vystrahy = new TextView[1];
        vystrahy[0] = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtVystrahy);
        (new htmlParser(vystrahy, 0) ).execute(new Integer[]{spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()});*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

but when I run my application spinner throws nullpointerexception. Any ideas on how to access it from fragment?

Here is my onCreateView which I believe is causing problem but I dont know how to fix it:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't work like that, what do you mean for spinner value? If you want to access to the spinner object you have to setup an interface which will be implemented by your activity and then in onActivityCreated you can call the method of that interface to do something. For example:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public interface MyInterface {
        void doSomethingWithSpinner();
    }

    public void doSomethingWithSpinner() {
        mySpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And your onActivityCreated:

```
if(getActivity() instanceof MyInterface) {
    ((MyInterface)getActivity()).doSomethingWithSpinner();
}
```

Comment: Explanation: I have a spinner which consists of 8 items. Based on item selected I retrieve specific part of HTMl from site. For example first item retrieves first div etc. So I just need listener which listenes to change of spinner item selected and then calls my method and parses it position of selected item

Comment: Then you don't need to take the spinner value from the fragment you can just create a method inside the fragment and call it from the activity when the spinner value changes